# webpack: webpack.config.js not loading fonts correctly

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have the following webpack snippet from https://survivejs.com/webpack/styling/loading/

```
{
         test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|otf)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options:{
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
```

which is intended to load fonts from my css/fonts directory.
My CSS directory has he following files:

```
type/
img/
design.css
```

I am able to use the css files and img files successfully in my project.

In type

I have a bunch of fonts in the following format

```
font-bold-v01.otf
font-bold-v01.woff
```

These are referenced in my 
design.css as follows:

```
  src:  url("./type/font-bold-v01.woff") format("woff"),
```

if i remove my web pack snippets I get errors. with my snippet I get no errors but the font does not take affect in components that work in non webpack projects.

any ideas?

gist of issue:
https://gist.github.com/MatthewJamesBoyle/2cebb7d1cdc76dc1692125d08fd9a31d

Answer (score 1):

Your fonts are being embedded in JS, that's why they cease to work when JS is not included in the HTML

Unfortunately this is webpack 1, you'll need to adjust for webpack 2

If you wish to build the CSS and assets(fonts/images) into standalone files:

install these plugins:

```
npm install --save-dev file-loader
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
```

use the ExtractTextPlugin to write the CSS:

```
// in your webpack.config.js file
 var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')


// in the "module" section of your webpack config
plugins:[
new ExtractTextPlugin(
            './css/[name].css',
            {
            allChunks:true,
        }),
//...
]
```

and use the file-loader (which, confusingly enough, is actually a file writer) 
instead of url-loader:

```
//in the "module/loaders" section of your webpack config

           {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
            },

           {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg|png|ico)(\?.+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                query: {
                    name: './static/[name].[ext]'
                }
           },
```

Note that the file loader specifies the `static` subfolder for the fonts to be wrritten in.

Make sure you set this in the top-level of your webpack config object:

```
 output: {
        publicPath: '/', // HTTP server base URL
        path: '/home/user/project/build', // filesystem path for the webpack bundles
}
//...
```

With this example config you'll get your fonts in this folder:

`/home/user/project/build/static`

and the CSS in

`/home/user/project/build/css`

Comment: Thanks for the help,I'm running into some problems with this still. I made a gist if you can help I'd be very grateful: https://gist.github.com/MatthewJamesBoyle/2cebb7d1cdc76dc1692125d08fd9a31d

Comment: oh, you need to install the plugin with npm (as stated in my answer) and import it with `var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');`

Comment: I adjusted the answer

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be in the right direction but didn't quite work.  I kept going but have hit a wall again. Mind having a quick look at my updated gist? I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: the file does not match the regex, please copy-paste the file loader section once again, I've updated it